# opening new tab on ipad triggered via AJAX not working

Tags: jquery, ipad

Seems something will not work with opening a new tab on an iPad after an AJAX call has been made.  Here is my code.

```
HTML:

<form id="confirmForm" action="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="hinp" value="1" />
</form>

<div id="someEl">Click</div>

JS:

$("#someEl").click(function(){
    var nid = 123;
    $.post("http://someurl.com", { eyeD: nid })
    .done(function () {
        $("#confirmForm").submit();
    });
});
```

On iPad this will not open a new tab.  Is this a bug? It opens fine with a regular web browser but not an iPad. Maybe some security or something?  Essentially I need to post a form on completion of the AJAX call that points to another server but open it in a new tab.

Comment: It seems the issue is in the .done() if I put the  $("#confirmForm").submit(); outside of that it works???

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in the .done() you cannot open a new window for some reason.  Not too sure if it is a bug, I even tried creating a function with the window.open and firing it from the .done() but still no luck.  Since there is a lack of answers I am considering this closed.  My work around was to open it after the AJAX call and make it synchronous so it is in order.

Comment: I believe this is because window opening can only happen on a user action (click) if it's done synchronously (which is what you've experienced). I just ran into this issue today, and it's annoying... damn security features...